# How to get the current profile name in an aura cmp?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, profile

I need to get the Profile name in my Aura component. I am converting my JS button to a Lightning Quick Action, so I need something like this in my component:

```
"{!$Profile.Name}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$Profile` in Lightning. For that, you need to write some Apex code. Please refer to this [blog post](https://andrescanavesi.wordpress.com/2018/09/09/migrate-user-profile-label-and-api-to-lightning-components/) for more details.

Comment: Can you include relevant code from the link in your answer or atleast how to retrieve profile id and name from apex

Answer (score 13):

It's not necessary to make an Apex call for this. You can retrieve the profile of the current user with a `force:recordData` component and an associated `aura:attribute` component, like so:

```
<aura:attribute name="CurrentUser" type="Object"/>
<force:recordData recordId="{!$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id}"
                  fields="Profile.Name"
                  targetFields="{!v.CurrentUser}"/>
```

Then you can access that data in your component like so:

```
{!v.CurrentUser.Profile.Name}
```

And in your component controller like so:

```
const username = component.get('v.CurrentUser')['Profile'].Name;
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it did not work for me. Do I need to populate anything for CurrentUser from the previous component/provide it as an input to this component?

Comment: @SfdcBat, no, there's no prerequisite for this technique. At least there wasn't in my case.

Answer (score 2):

The global value providers you are used to using in Visualforce are not available in lightning. The [Lightning Aura Components developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm) further expands on this and the supported global value providers.

So, you will have to get that info from the server in Apex using a callout from your quickactions component controller.